# FontAwesome en Asp.Net Core 2

Tags: html5, asp.net, asp.net-core, font-awesome

Estoy intentando incluir la libreria de FontAwesome en mi proyecto basado en .Net Core 2.x siendo incapaz de hacerlo funcionar. Para ello he probado lo siguiente.

En el fichero bundleconfig.json he incluido lo siguiente:

```js
// Configure bundling and minification for the project.
// More info at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=808241
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site.min.css",
    // An array of relative input file paths. Globbing patterns supported
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/css/site.css",
      "wwwroot/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/site.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/site.js"
    ],
    // Optionally specify minification options
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    // Optionally generate .map file
    "sourceMap": false
  }
]
```

Por otro lado, en el layout tengo la siguiente linea en la etiqueta

```html
    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>
```

Me gustaria saber ¿si es posible incluir esta libreria en un proyecto Asp.Net Core 2? y en caso contrario, 
¿Qué tipo de alternativas podría optar?

Comment: Has intentado incluirlo sin minificarlo?

Comment: Si, sin minificarlo, funciona correctamente.

Comment: Tambien incluyes las webfonts o soio el archivo css?

Comment: solo el archivo css, pero no me queda muy claro como se minifican las librerias, estoy empezando y estoy un poco perdido, sabes de algún tutorial donde expliquen esto?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x

Comment: Ahi explican todo pero esta en ingles.  Lo que si se es que no te va a funcionar si no incluyes las webfonts